# $n\times n$ matrix with char poly $x^{n-2}(x^2-1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n, (n\ge2)$ matrix with char poly $x^{n-2}(x^2-1)$ Then which of The following is true?

1. $A^n=A^{n-2}$,
2. $r(A)=2$,
3. $r(A)$ is atleast $2$,
4. there exist non zero vector $x,y$ such that $A(x+y)=x-y$,

Well, I can only see that 1 is true from the caley Hamilton Theorem, would you help other three are correct or not?

Comment: Do you know the Jordan normal form?

Comment: 2 is certainly true, as it has two distinct nonzero eigenvalues: $\pm 1$.

Comment: @Alex 2 is not necessarily true; 3 is.

Comment: @alex.jordan Of course, my bad. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $-1$ and $1$ are eigenvalues of $A$, the rank of $A$ is at least $2$. But it can be more than $2$, for example if $J$ is the matrix of size $(n-2)\times (n-2)$ given by $J=\pmatrix{0&1&0&\ldots &0\\ 0&0&1&\ldots &0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 0&0&\ldots&0&1\\
0&0&\ldots&0&0}$ and $A:=\pmatrix{A'&0\\ 0&J}$, where $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\-1&0}$. 
(in fact the rank is $2$ if $n=2$, and between $2$ and $n-1$ when $n>2$.

For the last question, use eigenvectors for the eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: For the last question, you could also just use any element of the kernel, and set $x = y$. (edit: oops, as long as $n > 2$, I mean)